# Current flowing differently in similar circuits

Tags: circuit-analysis, current

[image]

Top circuit has a 7 segment display. The ground pin on the display is connected to the negative terminal of the power supply.

Bottom circuit is the same circuit, but with a diode instead of display.

Why does the top have current flowing from ground into the negative terminal, but the bottom circuit has current flowing from the negative end of the diode to the power supply? Why isn't current flowing through the 7 segment display?

Comment: As a test, try adding a 500 ohm resistor between the node with the “0 V” label and the ground symbol, and let us know the result.

Comment: All Currents vectors are correct. from V+ to Load+ and load -  to V-.

Comment: WHY is that ground symbol on top and pointing up instead of down?  Don't do that.

Comment: The simulator seems to have a bug for showing cathode current to gnd. There is no Ground current anywhere. Link to your Sim.

Comment: @the photon same result, the display just reports burning out.

Comment: https://everycircuit.com/circuit/5526814964056064

Comment: @Tony can you explain why that's bad? I'm trying to learn

Comment: The ground or"earth" symbol represents parallel metal plates buried on the ground rather than in the sky so they should be drawn pointing down.

Comment: Is that convention? It's a 2D image without vertical orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Both circuits are the same and both are badly drawn. Current flows from the battery +, through the resistor, through the LED and back to the battery negative. Segment g is one LED of a common cathode display. The battery negative is chosen as ground reference which is common practice.

For clarity convention is to orientate the battery with + uppermost and to have ground symbols pointing down (to the ground). This way current flows from top to bottom of the schematic and the higher voltages are at the top.

The lack of current through the 7-segment display its probably due to a limitation of the simulation software. In practice it will.

Comment: I know the circuits are not perfect, but that isn't the point. I drew it up as a minimum ad hoc example to demonstrate an effect. I still don't understand why current is flowing differently in both. It may seem obvious why the current is like that, but keep in mind I'm new to all of this and need it to be explained.

Comment: The 7-segment display has a higher forward voltage drop for some reason. We'd need to know the part number it's modeled on.

Comment: I think the 7 segment display model has two LEDs in series for the digit segments.  This would cause the higer voltage across the display, and lower current.

Comment: The display is a component part in the every circuit simulator. I checked but unfortunately, they don't give out a datasheet for what they are modeling. I know that the back pin is ground, but that's about it.